# How to draw upper and lower smoothing lines

Tags: r

I have a ts plot with two loess lines in it (with different span).

Now I need to pick one of the loess lines and smooth the residuals. In this concrete upper and lower smoothing. It should look in the end like this:

[image: Upper and Lower Smoothing]

My first thought was really stupid.. That I only have to change the span value but of course that was completely wrong.

I was not able to find something that can help me on Google. I mean I found Upper and Lower Smoothing but only calculations. 
Does there exists a R command to draw these Smoothing lines easily?

I produced small table to make it easier to run (not the best but it works):

```
table <- structure(list(
  Months = c("1980-06", "1980-07", "1980-08", "1980-09", 
             "1980-10", "1980-11", "1980-12", "1981-01"), 
  Total = c(75000, 70000, 60000, 73000, 72000, 71000, 76000, 71000)),
  .Names = c("Monts", "Total of Killed Pigs"), 
  row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ts.obj <- ts(table$`Total of Killed Pigs`, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 2)

plot(ts.obj)

trend1 <- loess(ts.obj ~ as.numeric(time(ts.obj)), data = table, span =1)

predict1 <- predict(trend1)

matlines(as.numeric(time(ts.obj)), predict1, col ="blue")
```

For the completeness here is my original code (the table I got from this page: https://datamarket.com/data/set/22ky/monthly-total-number-of-pigs-slaughtered-in-victoria-jan-1980-august-1995#!ds=22ky&display=line) :

```
obj <- read.csv(file="PATH/monthly-total-number-of-pigs-sla.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
ts.obj <- ts(obj$Monthly.total.number.of.pigs.slaughtered.in.Victoria..Jan.1980...August.1995, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 12)
plot(ts.obj)
trend1 <- loess (ts.obj ~ as.numeric(time(ts.obj)) , data = obj, span =1)
trend2 <- loess (ts.obj ~ as.numeric(time(ts.obj)) , data = obj, span =0.1)
predict1 <- predict (trend1)
predict2 <- predict (trend2)
matlines(as.numeric(time(ts.obj)), predict1, lty =1, col="blue")
matlines(as.numeric(time(ts.obj)), predict2, col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subset` argument of `loess`.

Setup:

```
tm    <- time(ts.ojb)
trend <- loess(ts.obj ~ tm)
pred  <- trend$fitted
resid <- trend$residuals
```

Computing `loess` for the positive (negative) residuals gives us upper (lower) smoothing. Therefore

```
indexU <- resid > 0
upper  <- loess(resid ~ t, subset = indexU)$fitted
```

When plotting, don't forget to add the offset back, i.e. `trend[indexU]+upper`.